# Google test can't find a tested dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, testing, dll, googletest

I've added google test project to my solution as descried into [MS manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2019). I added on creating test project stage reference to my project that I want to test. My project is a dll. In test project references I can see proper path to my original dll. Test project exe is built into different folder than the dll of the project that I want to test.
When I run my test project it says that my dll cannot be located.
Obviously, if I will build test exe into same folder everything will work, but is there other way to make my test application properly load dll?

Comment: If this is still actual, there are couple of ways: manually add reference <project right click> --> "Add" --> References. But you don't really need that if you link your DLL (project?) with unit test program

Comment: See [this example](https://github.com/aregtech/areg-sdk) project. The unit test is linked with the shared library (dll).

Answer (score 0):

I would statically link the code-under-test into the test application. This means that you do not use the DLL during your tests and thus it is not needed.

If you do want to use the DLL, you can:

- Use `SetDllDirectory()` to add a directory to the DLL search path. See [Search Order for Desktop Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications) for details.
- Dynamically load the DLL using `LoadLibrary()` and specify the exact path to the DLL. You need to use `GetProcAddress()` to access and call the functions in the DLL.